# ERROR 1140 (42000) aggregated query by groupby?

Tags: mysql

i am running this query on online `mysql` editor
-- Find the total sales of each salesman

```
SELECT SUM(total_sales), emp_id
FROM works_with
GROUP BY client_id;
```

and I am getting this error message

> ERROR 1055 (42000) at line 111: Expression #2 of `SELECT` list is not in `GROUP BY` clause and contains nonaggregated column `'test.works_with.emp_id'` which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

what could be the problem? thanks

Comment: its because of `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: The query you showed us should _not_ be generating this error.  I think you ran some other query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i edited the earlier question. Kindly check this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to aggregate sales over each employee, each of which would have one or more clients, then this version of the query is what you should be using:

```
SELECT SUM(total_sales), emp_id
FROM works_with
GROUP BY emp_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(total_sales), emp_id
FROM works_with
GROUP BY **client_id**;
```

The issue is in group by **client_id** change it with emp_id